# Return a list of files based on file extension with a javascript expression

Tags: javascript, expression, workflow

I'm having trouble returning a list of files based on file extension and don't have enough experience with javascript to know the right syntax to accomplish this. The expression handles file.basename but not file.nameext, so I'm not sure how to effectively parse. This is to write a javascript expression in a Common Workflow Language expression tool, as part of a workflow.

Assuming the directory has .txt, .gz, and .gz.foo, I'd like to return a list of all the .gz files.

```
${
  var gzs = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.dir.listing.length; i++) {
    var file = inputs.dir.listing[i];
    if file.basename.match(".gz"); {
      gzs.push(file);
    }
  }

  return {
    "gzs": gzs
  };
}
```

Comment: Is this on the server? Can you give more details? For example tag it with framework or node.js ? It does not really look like proper JS to me

Comment: That's not legal js syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the file name using `split` and dot (`.`) as delimiter. This will give an array. In this array check for the last element. If that matches then put the file in the array.

Secondly you are using a `return` statement but I cannot see a function. Put your code inside a function

```js
let inputs = {
  dir: {
    listing: ['abc.gz', 'def.sb', 'ghi.gz', 'jkl.er.km']
  }
}

function giveGzFile() {
  let gzs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.dir.listing.length; i++) {
    var file = inputs.dir.listing[i];
    let splitedFileName = file.split('.');
    if (splitedFileName[splitedFileName.length - 1] === "gz") {
      gzs.push(file);
    }
  }
  return {
    "gzs": gzs
  };
}
console.log(giveGzFile())
```

Comment: Hi, nice one, what about use the regex for testing the file name?

Comment: yes, but I believe you answer more extended than mine and using the regex just a suggestion for getting you answer little bit better.

Answer (score 1):

```
\.gz$
```

is more correct regex for you. dot symbol should be escaped, and `$` will check .gz substring only in the end of line.